# Don't need to two function for + overload?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I overloaded + operator on c++ like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Cent
{
private:
    int m_nCent;

public:
    Cent(){ };
    Cent(int n);
    int getCent() const;
    void setCent(int);
    friend Cent operator+(const Cent &c1, const Cent &c2);
    friend Cent operator+(const Cent &c1, const int);
};

Cent::Cent(int n)
{
    setCent(n);
}

int Cent::getCent() const
{
    return Cent::m_nCent;
}


void Cent::setCent(int n)
{
    Cent::m_nCent = n;
}

Cent operator+(const Cent &c1, const Cent &c2)
{
    return Cent(c1.getCent() + c2.getCent());
}

Cent operator+(const Cent &c1, const int n)
{
    return Cent(c1.getCent() + n);
}

int main()
{
    Cent c1(5);
    Cent c2(4);
    Cent sum;

    sum = c1 + c2;

    std::cout << sum.getCent() << std::endl;

    sum = c1 + 7;

    std::cout << sum.getCent() << std::endl;

    sum = 9 + c1;

    std::cout << sum.getCent() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Based on this code, i must overload + operator with two function, a function for (Cent,int) and another for (int,Cent), i implemented only (Cent,int) case but on main i use + operator for (int,Cent) and it's work truly! What's wrong for me?

I use GCC v4.8.2 on Linux 3.13.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have an implicit conversion constructor `Cent(int)`. The `9 + c1` call will expand to `Cent(9) + c1` and call the `Cent, Cent` overload.

Comment: In other words, you only need one overload, `Cent operator+(const Cent &c1, const Cent &c2);`

Comment: By marking the constructor as `explicit Cent(int n);`, then you won't be able to convert implicitly and will get an error in the line `9 + c1`.

Answer (score 1):

Your class has conversion constructor

```
Cent(int n);
```

that allows to convert implicitly an object of type `int` to a temporary object of type `Cent`

If you would for example declare the constructor as

```
explicit Cent(int n);
```

then the code with the call of the operator would not be compiled.

Or if you would declare the operator the following way removing qualifier `const` for the first parameter

```
friend Cent operator+( Cent &c1, const Cent &c2);
```

then again the code would not be compiled.